# Read a value from a JSON key when the key is unknown/random

Tags: ruby

My JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "item": {
        "-LVShDSBr5tvs0wGkc0JJ": {
            "text": "H"
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "-LEVSZndgiqwhgnytO3Kr": {
            "text": "Hatem"
        }
    }
}
```

I can read each `item` object, but I need to reach the `text` value. To do that, I need to get through the random ID that's one level above that. How do I read what's within that key?

I have this:

```
items.each do |item|
   # gets one item successfully
   # but im unable to read the key within since it's unknown
   text = item[:unknown_key][:text]
end
```

Comment: Please post plain text, not screenshots. The latter are extremely hard to copy-paste to test.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Updated!

Comment: I suppose it’s an array or something; current object would have the first `item` value overwritten by second one; hashes cannot have same keys.

Comment: What is `items`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Hash#values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
texts =
  items.map do |item|
    item.values.first[:text]
  end
```

If you expect more than one `item`, play around with mapping values to their `[:text]`s.

Comment: JSON data is nothing but hash so how you could process with 2 same keys provided by OP?

Comment: @ray no, unless you have your own json parser written.

Comment: thanks, I did not know it, any reference for how to do it in ruby/rails will be appreciated!